Reversing data processing inequality for f-divergences for certain types of corruptions
Consider a random variable $X$. Let $Z ~ \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$. Let $Y = X + Z$. For distributions $p_X, q_X$ and $p_Y, q_Y$, data processing inequality gives us
$$D_f(p_y \| q_y) \leq D_f(p_x \| q_x)$$.
We know this becomes an equality when $\sigma = 0$. Is it possible to get a bound the other way, i.e.
$$D_f(p_x \| q_x) \leq \alpha D_f(p_y \| q_y)$$,
Where $\alpha$ is a constant somehow related to $\sigma$?
